# How to add a joined column to a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

A table `clients` has a column `country`. This contains a code

- NL
- GB
- etc.

The long name being in table countries. I can place a datagridview on a window and populate it with an sql query for example:

```
Dim myda As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dbDataset As New DataTable
Dim bSource As New BindingSource
Dim query = “SELECT clients.client_id, clients.client_name, countries.country country FROM clients LEFT OUTER JOIN countries ON countries.country_code = clients.country WHERE ..."

conn.Open()
Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
myda.SelectCommand = cmd
myda.Fill(dbDataset)
bSource.DataSource = dbDataset
DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
myda.Update(dbDataset)
conn.Close()
```

This works and the the long name is displayed **but** only if I give the joined column an alias the same as the column name in the clients table i.e. `country`. This overwrites the clients column and I cannot add another joined column to the grid.

Is there a way that I can for example display *GB* and *Great Britain* in the same grid?

Second question: How can I do this without a datagridview? I.e. dragging individual columns to the window. Using a table adaptor fill method sort of works with a straight query, but how can I achieve the above?

Comment: There's no reason why `clients.country AS coountry_cd, `, for example, wouldn't work. 2nd question - one question at a time is expected, and when you ask it, please elaborate on your goal because it is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for answering and I am sorry about the second question. I am not very good at explaining myself but: The grid is from one table - clients which has a column 'country'. If I join another table (countries) ...clients.country as country_code ... JOIN.... as country then the joined column takes the place of the column country in the grid but the country_code is then not displayed. In other words I cannot add a column to the grid this way. I can replace columns but not add a column. I am definitely missing something elementary, but what?
Anyway, thanks for listening.

Comment: Hi, I am getting there - slowly. I found a way to add a column. DataGridView1.Columns.Add("country_code", "country_code") only I can't populate it. ... clients.country as country_code doesn't work. I place the command after the comm.open() in the above code.

Comment: You're making it too much work. If your grid has `AutoGenerateColumns` true, then it will create columns for whatever your DataTable contains. Something you haven't shown is wrong. [Here](http://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) is an example of using a grid. While not directly an answer to your question, it might help with the concepts.

Comment: THANK YOU Crowcoder! AutoGenerateColumns did the trick.
Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: Just one comment. When I set AutoGenerateColumns to True the grid indices are increased by 3. In order to get the value of the first column 
instead of DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value  I have to use DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(3).Value
Wierd.
btw, how do I mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: I have posted an answer. Regarding cell indexes, it may be that it is including id columns that you were not doing manually? I can't say, but it is better style to access [`BindingSource.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current(v=vs.110).aspx) than to get the data out of a UI component like a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true` to have all columns in your query automatically displayed.